# How to filter TCP option with wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I'm trying to filter the packets by TCP options in wireshark. For example, I want to get all packets with the option Maximum Segment Size (with kind number 2). However, I find if I use the filter as `tcp.option_kind == 2`, I'll only get the packets with the first option as kind 2. However, packets may have multiple options, which means I couldn't get the packets with its second option as kind 2. Any idea to improve this filter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I find if I use the filter as `tcp.option_kind == 2`, I'll only get the packets with the first option as kind 2.

If that's truly happening, it's a bug.  `tcp.option_kind == 2` is supposed to match packets in which *any* of the instances of `tcp.option_kind` are equal to 2, so it should find packets that contain that option even if it's not the first option.

You should file a bug on [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org/) for this, and attach a capture that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll reproduce the case again. So do you mean `tcp.option_kind == 2` should already be the correct filter for options (not `tcp.options.type` or sth else)?

Comment: No, it's not `tcp.options.type`, it's `tcp.option_kind` (at least for that option).